# Can I create unrestricted schema with sql database like the one sed in django?

Tags: sql, django, firebase, nosql, schema

In mongodb or firebase I can create `{title:"sothigs, content:"somthing"}` then I can create other object with only title for example `{title:"second title"}` or I even can create object with new values that i never defined before.
Is it possible to do with django sql databases?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL as your DB, then you can use [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) in Django. Otherwise, check out more of the vendor-specific fields available in Django. This will lock you in to whichever database you end up using, however, PostgreSQL is a very good multi-purpose relational DB so I highly recommend using it.